# Android repeatOnLifecycle in fragment inside ViewPager2

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-viewpager2

If I add the following code snippet to a "normal" fragment it gets started and cancelled as expected when navigating to and from the fragment, but if I add this to fragment inside a view pager 2 it is not cancelled even though the fragmens `onPause` method is invoked. Is this by design or am I missing something?

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
        try {
            while (isActive) {
                println("Fragment alive....")
                delay(1000)
            }
        } catch (ex: CancellationException) {
            println("Cancelled fragment...")
            throw ex
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that depends on your `ViewPager2` adapters implementation, may be proper behavior, when some recycling is implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no sure if I got your question right, but I can already tell that you're relaying on the wrong lifecycle event if you wish that your code gets executed  when the Fragment is visible, for that you need to use `repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)`. Using this your code will start executing as soon as the Fragment is [visible](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle) and gets cancelled when it gets paused.
Using `repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)` your code will start executing when the Fragment is started (ready to get displayed) and gets cancelled when it gets stopped.

Comment: Ah of course.. stupid mistake. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: happens to the best of us, you're welcome

Comment: @MuhannadFakhouri can you please check this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70593277/11560810)